# How to close keyboard in textfield

Tags: ios, swift

Today I was following this tutorial: http://youtu.be/9rq4P-L-z8U. However, when it came to the part where it showed how to close the keyboard after pressing the `button`, I followed the instructions, but when I started the simulator, the keyboard simulator never appeared on the screen.
How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!


    @IBAction func ButtonMethod(sender: AnyObject) {
        Label.text = TextField.text
        TextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func ButtonMethod(sender: AnyObject) {   
      self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This will remove the keyboard from your screen when you press on a button

EDIT: Since your title is different than your question this is the answer:
[image]

Uncheck connect hardware keyboard

Answer (score 0):

if when you start edit text box and keyboard is not showing than on simulator functions , go to Hardware->KeyBoard->Connect HardWare KeyBoard and uncheck it!!

otherwise in button action just write

```
YourTextField.resignFirstResponder = true
```

may this will help you also check for textfield delegate connected or not

Comment: I said exactly the same lol, so why would you post the same answer?

Comment: oh yeah! but image you put takes time to load so i didn't see it!